# How to read mongodb 5.0 collections in powershell

Tags: c#, mongodb, powershell, collections

I am trying to read the documents of a collection in mongodb5.0 using powershell with the below code of piece.

I am getting error at the last line **$collection.find($query)**

Method invocation failed because [MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject,
System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]] does not contain a method named
'Find'.

```
function Get-MongoDBCollection {
Param(
    $database,
    $CollectionName,
    $settings = $null, #[MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionSetting]
    $returnType = [PSOBJECT]
)
    $method = $database.GetType().GetMethod('GetCollection')
    $GenericMethod = $method.MakeGenericMethod($returnType)
    $GenericMethod.Invoke($database,[object[]]($CollectionName,$settings))
}

$mongoDbDriverPath = 'C:\Users\testuser\'
$mongoServer = 'localhost:27017'

Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Driver.dll"

add-type -path "$mongoDbDriverPath\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$mongoDbDriverPath\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$mongoDbDriverPath\MongoDB.Driver.dll"
add-type -path "$mongoDbDriverPath\DnsClient.dll";
#Add-Type -path "$mongoDbDriverPath\MongoDb.Driver.Core.dll"    
Add-Type -Path "$mongoDbDriverPath\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$mongoDbDriverPath\System.ValueTuple.dll"

$databaseName = 'myDatabase'
$collectionName = 'myCollection'

$client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://$mongoServer"
$database = $client.GetDatabase($databaseName)

$Collection = Get-MongoDBCollection $database $collectionName
#$Collection = Get-MongoDBCollection $database $collectionName -returnType  ([MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument])

$query = new-object MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument('Name','john')

$collection.find($query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` is an extension method, and unlike the C# compiler, PowerShell can't figure out how to resolve those. You have to reference the underlying static type in which the extension method was defined to invoke it:

```
[MongoDb.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions]::Find($collection, $query)
```

But since `Find` is also generic, we'll need to use the method-equivalent of `MakeGenericType()` to create a type-specific version we can invoke:

```
function Find-MongoDbDocument
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]]
    $collection,

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]]$filter = $null,

    [ValidateRange(1,100000)]
    [int]$Limit
  )

  $documentType = [MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]

  # Discover the relevant Find() extension method overload
  $findDefinition = [MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions].GetMethods() |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Find' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 3} |Select-Object -First 1

  # Make a type-parameter-specific version of Find() 
  $findBsonMethod = $findDefinition.MakeGenericMethod($documentType)

  # Invoke Find()
  $result = $findBsonMethod.Invoke($null, @($collection, $filter, $null))

  # Limit the result set size, if requested
  if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Limit')){
    $result = $result.Limit($Limit)
  }

  # Fetch the results
  $cursor = $result.ToCursor()
  while($cursor.MoveNext([System.Threading.CancellationToken]::None)){
    Write-Output $cursor.Current 
  }
}
```

**Note** that I'm using `[BsonDocument]` instead of `[psobject]` as the document type - the MongoDB driver already has native support for deserializing to `[BsonDocument]` (but not `[psobject]`).

Use like so:

```
# Obtain collection object 
$collection = Get-MongoDBCollection $database $collectionName -returnType $([MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument])

# Define filter
$filter = [MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]::new('Name', 'John')

# Fetch first 100 matching documents
Find-MongoDbDocument -Collection $collection -Filter $filter -Limit 100
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but it is giving the same error. can you provide me full code to read the documents with .net driver 2.13.1 (MongoDB shell version v5.0.2 & PowerShell version 5.0)

Comment: any response on it? I am waiting for this solution>

Comment: @kuldeepSingh I've updated the answer with a more complete example

Comment: thanks a ton. it resolved my issue. thank you once again. God Bless you.